# How do I make the green background color be half of the whole div?

Tags: html, css

I wonder why the div bar doesn't show green background color halfway, from left to middle.  It just show the whole div bar.   What could be the problem?   THanks..

```css
.BioUploadProgressBar p {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  border: 1px inset #446;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.BioUploadProgressBar p.initialize {
  /*background: #0c0 none 0 0 no-repeat;*/
  background-color: #0c0;
  background-image: none;
  background-position: 50% 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='BioUploadProgressBar'>
    <p class="initialize">Upload file 0 %</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .BioUploadProgressBar p.initialize { width:50% } . Your container is 100% width of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your HTML is incorrect and your CSS is even more incorrect, you're using background properties that applies to background images, not colors, change your HTML to this:

```
<div>
    <div class='BioUploadProgressBar'>
        <div class="initialize">Upload file 0 %</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your CSS to this:

```
.BioUploadProgressBar {
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    border: 1px solid #446;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.initialize {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    background: #0c0;
    width:175px;
    ;
    padding:5px;
}
```

[see FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypjdr0a5/)

Comment: Interesting.  I saw few people's examples that show it can be done with P tag.  I thought with HTML5, anyone is possible but I thought wrong.  :-/

Comment: technically, you can do it with a `p` tag, but it's always better to use `divs`. While HTML5 (with some help of CSS) provides you with great freedom to adapt elements to do things they are not supposed to do by default, the idea is always to try to use the correct element. If anything, at least for semantic purposes, you would never expect a `<p>` tag to actually be a box

Answer (score 3):

Background-Position only applies to Background-Image. You'll have these options:

- Use a Background-Image (But also have an additional Request)
- Use a second DIV
- Use a CSS Gradient (http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ - No IE8 and stuff)

Comment: CSS gradients are a bad choice. There's currently a bug in chrome that does not calculate them accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```css
.progress {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.cpu {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  transition: width 2.0s ease 0s;
  background-color: #FF6633;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" style="width:500px;">
  <div id="cpu" class="cpu" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%">
    <span>10</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradient solution via [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

```css
.partialGradiend{
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,204,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,204,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,204,0,0) 51%, rgba(0,204,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,204,0,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,204,0,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(0,204,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,204,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,204,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,204,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,204,0,0) 51%,rgba(0,204,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,204,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,204,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,204,0,0) 51%,rgba(0,204,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,204,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,204,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,204,0,0) 51%,rgba(0,204,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,204,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,204,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,204,0,0) 51%,rgba(0,204,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00cc00', endColorstr='#0000cc00',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
  width:300px;
  
  border: 1px inset #446;
    border-radius: 5px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="partialGradiend" style="">
  50%
</div>
```